# Why was this question closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

["Introduce person to object" or "introduce object to person"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84467/introduce-person-to-object-or-introduce-object-to-person)

I'd like to know what may have been considered off topic. The question is about the "usage", so I believe it's right on topic of this site.